# Wait for image to be uploaded before continuing function with Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image using Firebase Storage. The problem i'm having is when i'm calling my image upload function, the upload task is very slow and it ends up running last in my main function when it is actually called further up.

Is there a way to wait for storageRef.putData to finish before continuing the rest of the function?

Would possibly reducing compression quality from 1 be faster?

Here is my function:

```
func newImageUrl(){
    let key = self.itemId
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(userID).child("SubCategory").child(self.itemTitle!).child(key!).child("ItemImages.jpg")

    guard let imageData = self.itemImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return }

    print("starting image upload!")
    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            return
        }

        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let urlStr = url else{
                return
            }
                let urlFinal = (urlStr.absoluteString)
                self.imageFinalUrl = urlFinal
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED func --

```
func newImageUrl(completion:@escaping((String?) -> () )) {
let key = self.itemId
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { completion(nil) ; return }
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(userID).child("SubCategory").child(self.itemTitle!).child(key!).child("ItemImages.jpg")

guard let imageData = self.itemImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { completion(nil) ; return }

print("starting image upload!")
storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
        return
    }

    storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        guard let urlStr = url else{
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let urlFinal = (urlStr.absoluteString)
        self.imageFinalUrl = urlFinal
        completion(urlFinal)
        }
    }
}
```

Example main function:

```
func updateItemDetail(){
    print("this is running 1")
    self.newImageUrl { (str) in
        print(str)
    }
    print("this is running 2")
```

Console prints:

```
this is running 1
starting image upload!
this is running 2
Optional("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/.....etc")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a completion

```
func newImageUrl(completion:@escaping((String?) -> () )) {
    let key = self.itemId
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { completion(nil) ; return }
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(userID).child("SubCategory").child(self.itemTitle!).child(key!).child("ItemImages.jpg")

    guard let imageData = self.itemImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { completion(nil) ; return }

    print("starting image upload!")
    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            return
        }

        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let urlStr = url else{
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            let urlFinal = (urlStr.absoluteString)
            self.imageFinalUrl = urlFinal
            completion(urlFinal)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Call

```
newImageUrl { (str) in
  print(str)
  // do your next work here
}
```

Comment: Does not work for some reason, the storageRef.putData function is still being called last after a delay. It will print "starting image upload", do the rest of my main function, delay 1-3 seconds (depends on file size i'm assuming) and then it runs storageRef.putData..etc

Comment: Adding new code to the main question to make it the problem more clear

Comment: it's working , now put the logic you need to do after the upload directly below the `print(str)` as in answer

Comment: I understand now, it seems to work thank you for your help!

Comment: Excellent answer!!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

There is now a method in firebase storage that you can use to put files asynchronsly and therefore you can simply use `await` to wait for the upload to complete.

e.g

```
let uploadMetadata = try await storageRef.putDataAsync(imageData, metadata: nil)
//Do whatever you want to after completion
```